# Asterisk - wrong context - inbound calls

Tags: handler, asterisk, sip

I'm getting this warning:

```
pbx.c:6647 __ast_pbx_run: Channel 'SIP/ipgate.sk-00000002' sent to invalid extension but no invalid handler: context,exten,priority=to_pstn,0650941362,1
```

When I'm trying to make outbound or inbound call, dialplan goes to the context which I use only with outbound call [to_pstn]. Do you guys know what could cause this problem?

From the *CLI (verbose 5) I get only this. The same message for inbound and outbound:

```
-- Executing [0902135633@default:1] Goto("SIP/201-00000005", "to_pstn,0902135633,1") in new stack
    -- Goto (to_pstn,0902135633,1)
[Mar 19 21:01:30] WARNING[4846][C-00000005]: pbx.c:6647 __ast_pbx_run: Channel 'SIP/201-00000005' sent to invalid extension but no invalid handler: context,exten,priority=to_pstn,0902135633,1
```

extensions.conf

```
[from_pstn]
exten => _X.,1,Goto(IVR_IN,100,1)

[to_pstn]
exten => _XXXXXXXXXX,n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@my_provider,20)
```

sip.conf

```
[my_provider]
canreinvite=yes
username=**myUSERNAME**
fromuser=**myFROMUSER**
secret=**mySECRET**
context=from_pstn
type=peer
fromdomain=**myDOMAIN**
host=ipgate.sk
dtmfmode=rfc2833
disallow=all
allow=alaw
allow=ulaw
nat=yes
insecure=port,invite
```

Comment: You need more debug.Check sip debug for which peer selected and check dialplan to see what other context you have

Answer (score 2):

Your `extensions.conf` has an error:

```
[to_pstn]
exten => _XXXXXXXXXX,n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@my_provider,20)
```

should be

```
[to_pstn]
exten => _XXXXXXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@my_provider,20)
```

... you cannot start a priority with "n".

Try `dialplan show to_pstn` at the console.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the stupid mistake but it didn't solve the problem. When I'm calling from a pstn (my cell phone) to my asterisk, dialplan still goes to the wrong context "to_pstn" instead of "from_pstn". I'm calling a number "0650941362" from my cell phone and this is what happens in a dial plan:
`Goto("SIP/provider_domain.com-00000012", "to_pstn,0655541362,1")`
`Dial("SIP//provider_domain.com-00000012", "SIP/0655541362@my_povider,20")`
Asterisk is trying to make an outbound call to a number I'm calling to

Comment: I did `core restart` and it works like a charm. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help.  Please "accept" my answer so that other folks with a similar problem can find it.